# Parse Platform default ACL

Tags: parse-platform, acl

**Story:**
I'm developing simple Angular web-app using Parse Platform for backend and straight API calls (no parse platform libraries). I have couple of tables and login - everything is working. However it came time to restrict access via Access Controls such that one user can't access data of another and here we I hit a problem.

**Question:**
Given user is logged in, how to default newly created/updated object to have ACL specifically to the creator (currently logged-in user)?

**Additionally:**

- I would assume there is a way to set parse platform to do it by default (and docs mention it) but I can't find out how.
- I want to void manually pass ACL settings in each request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is through [`beforeSave`](https://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#beforesave) trigger. It would be something like this:

```js
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave('MyClass', ({ original, object, user }) => {
  if (!original) { // New object is being created
    object.setACL(new Parse.ACL(user));
  }
});
```

Comment: Looks like there is no built-in option. Either each create/update request must contain ACL or custom Cloud on the Parse side. Couple more details here: https://community.parseplatform.org/t/default-acl-to-the-logged-in-user-on-create-update/1034